# Listbox item select with sender like Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8, listbox

Hi I have lite problem with my listbox. When I click on item in listbox(text or image) everything is working but when I click on blank space in item row then item is not selected but I dont know where can be problem because every one row/item is used like grid which contains images and text and I have set tag to binding in grid but item is selected ony if I click on text or image.

```
 private void userTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Grid;
        if (button != null)
        {
            var subject = MyDatasMessagesUserList.FirstOrDefault(sub => sub == button.Tag);
            if (subject != null)
            {
                IdOfChoosenUser = subject.MessengeFromId;
            }
        }}


<ListBox x:Name="lbMessagesUsersList" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="13"   ItemsSource="{Binding MyDatasMessagesUserList }" Margin="0,0,0,80">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" Tapped="userTapped"  Tag="{Binding}" >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="layoutGraphics/logo120.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="5,5,0,0"></Image>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbMessengerName" Text="{Binding MessengerName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                   Foreground="#FF02416C"
                                                   FontSize="16" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,20,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="120"/>
                            <Image x:Name="imgMessengerIsOffline" 
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                                    Margin="10,0,20,0" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Source="{Binding isUserOnline}"  Width="20" Height="20">
                            </Image>
                        </Grid>
                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF6FB7FF" Grid.Row="1"  Height="1"                          Margin="0,0,0,-20">
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your grid in the DataTemplate inside a ListBoxItem (and set the tap event on the ListBoxItem) or set the background of your grid to transparent and the tap event should work correctly.

```
private void userTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as ListBoxItem;
    if (button != null)
    {
        var subject = MyDatasMessagesUserList.FirstOrDefault(sub => sub == button.Tag);
        if (subject != null)
        {
            IdOfChoosenUser = subject.MessengeFromId;
        }
    }}


<ListBox x:Name="lbMessagesUsersList" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="13"   ItemsSource="{Binding MyDatasMessagesUserList }" Margin="0,0,0,80">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <ListBoxItem Tapped="userTapped"  Tag="{Binding}">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,10"  >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="layoutGraphics/logo120.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="5,5,0,0"></Image>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbMessengerName" Text="{Binding MessengerName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                               Foreground="#FF02416C"
                                               FontSize="16" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,20,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="120"/>
                        <Image x:Name="imgMessengerIsOffline" 
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                                Margin="10,0,20,0" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Source="{Binding isUserOnline}"  Width="20" Height="20">
                        </Image>
                    </Grid>
                    <Rectangle Fill="#FF6FB7FF" Grid.Row="1"  Height="1"                          Margin="0,0,0,-20">
                    </Rectangle>
                </Grid>
             </ListBoxItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Hi Benoit. My grid is in datateplate inside listbox and when I try set   the tap event on the ListBoxItem it not working, and background of  grid to transparent not working too. I think problem is in sender as Grid

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer with the code with wrapping the Grid with a ListBoxItem, not sure of that was how you did it. Also the ItemContainer style had a Padding which was preventing the tap tobe intercepted when you tap just on the limit of the item so I removed it too.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is because you have 3 columns in your `Grid` but you're only using two of them. Therefore, there is no object for you to click on, so the item does not get selected. I guess that you can fix your problem by

1) Removing the third column of the `Grid`.

or

2) Adding a `Rectangle` (or any other control) into the third column of the `Grid`.

Comment: um no I have image in coloumn 3, only I dont push it here. Problem will be  in something else.